# Is my LINQ query safe and efficient?

Tags: c#, linq

I am relatively new to LINQ queries as I normally just use plain SQL to get my data back but i am changing for the good - Anyway obviously with SQL you pass in parameters so you do not get any SQL injections etc. Now the LINQ query I have written I think is safe but I am thinking it may be able to done a little easier and more efficient.

So I am passing in my data in the query from the model which is being sent from the view and my tables columns are being called from the `ProjectLinqDataContext` class. Is this safe? is there anything which I am doing which is not best practice.

```
 var context = new ProjectLinqDataContext();
 var user = from y in context.Customers
               where y.CustomerUsername == model.Email && y.CustomerPassword == model.Password
               select y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ProjectLinqDataContext is disposable so make sure to wrap the usage in a using statement. Efficiency will be based on how your database is indexed. The query itself looks fine. You can also use method syntax for a more fluent and object oriented look. This doesn't affect anything, but I think it's much more readable.

```
using(var context = new ProjectLinqDataContext())
{
    var user = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CustomerUsername == model.Email && y.CustomerPassword == model.Password);
    //do something with user if it's not null
}
```

Make sure your password has been hashed and salted of course.

Comment: You should also explain that your code **executes** the query, while the OP's code doesn't, and why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that does look a lot cleaner.. in terms of FirstOrDefault will that return null if no customer is found - this is nice as you don't have to use is .any() all the time? so is kind of like a TOP 1 SQL query?

Comment: my query does still get the data back @cFrozenDeath..  all held in user object.. so by execute you mean actually performing the query or..?

Comment: @TedMarley your version represents a delayed executed query, which means you are not asking for it to run immediately. First will throw an Exception if the query returns no elements, FirstOrDefault will return default(T) (null or the Struct default) instead of throwing the exception. FirstOrDefault won't give you an IEnumerable(T) however, just T.

Comment: ahhhhh @cFrozenDeath thats makes so much sense now!! thanks for explaining that!

Comment: should you always use lambda expressions like the example given by manovision as mine seems a little strange when comparing it against this one.. @cFrozenDeath

Comment: @TedMarley I forgot to mention that the delayed executed query it's not because how you construct your LinQ (query syntax (yours) or method syntax (answer)), but because the FirstOrDefault method instructs LinQ to perform the query. See this post http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/83057/linq-style-preference for your last question

Comment: Thanks cFrozenDeath for mentioning lazy loaded vs executed. @TedMarley, queries that result in an IQueryable aren't executed against the database until iterated. This helps a lot with not loading datasets until needed. You can also combine statements together such as search terms and then only execute the query when needed. Whole books are written on this this. Have fun with this, it's such a difference from executing raw T-SQL. You'll never want to go back.

Comment: i don't want to go back already literally so much cleaner and so much less lines of code then having to do a sqlconnection then sqlcommand then the actually SQL query and then loop through the data! LinQ is what dreams are made from why have i just started this!! haha thanks a lot @ManOVision

Comment: @TedMarley You asked if you should always use lambda statements and there is no set rule. First or Single will execute a TOP 1 so lambda here is common. You can use them on nearly any LINQ method and combine them such as Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault() to do the same thing. Where returns an IQueryable and FirstOrDefault will actually execute so they can be chained like this. Start with a simple dataset and test all the LINQ methods and you'll start to see where the lambda fits better or not.

Comment: yeah i have been reading a few other articles/questions and it seems do which ever one best suits the query you need. Both are best practices so i guess if its loads of join() then just use a query syntax due to how unreadable the method syntax looks. - Thanks for all your advice @ManOVision i feel like i can be a linq expert with some good practice now. Bit difficult to get your head round when you first look at the lambda expressions but when you get it you get it (like a lightbulb turns on)! Cheers :D

Comment: @TedMarley If you are doing loads of join(), then you doing it wrong.  You should have your navigation properties set up, and then you never do any joins at all.